# LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is not triggering onLocationChanged

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am trying to create a location detector without using GPS. but LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is not triggering onLocationChanged. can suggestion?

```
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getlocation= may();
    longitude =getlocation.getLongitude(); //location.getLongitude();
    latitude = getlocation.getLatitude();//location.getLatitude();
    String str = "Latitude: " + latitude + "Longitude: " + longitude;

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one you don't appear to have any references to the actual location object in the OnLocationChanged method. Also because NETWORK_PROVIDER is so inaccurate your going to have to travel a large distance to register any change in location with some broadcast towers not providing a location service at all.

My recommendation would be to use LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation to provide the initial fix. You will however have to wait a long period to find a new location without gps

LocationManager Doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)